# PHP Ignoring if statements (num rows)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make an invite code system, but PHP is ignoring my `if(num_rows)`.

This is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['signupSubmit'])){
    //check whether user details are empty
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['confirm_password']) && !empty($_POST['invite_code'])){
        //password and confirm password comparison
        $invite_code = $_POST['invite_code'];
        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM codes WHERE used = '0' AND code = '$invite_code'");
        $rowCount = $result->num_rows;
        if ($rowCount < 0)
        {    
            $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error';
            $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Registration requires an invite.'; 
        }
        $result1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM codes WHERE used = '0' AND code = '$invite_code'");
        /*if ($db->num_rows($result1))*/
        $rowCount1 = $result1->num_rows;
        if ($rowCount1 > 0)
        {
            $invby = $result1->fetch_assoc();
            $invby = $invby['by'];
        }
```

Also what I tried was:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) and if(mysqli_num_rows($result1)>0)
```

Edit, just tried doing:

```
if (!$result) and if ($result1)
```

And these didn't work either.

Edit 2:

I tried doing:

```
$fetched1 = $result1->fetch_assoc();
$rowCount = $fetched1['total'];
        if($rowCount == 0)
        {    
            exit("Registration requires an invite.");
        }
```

But what happens is, even if i enter a correct one it still exit's..?

But these also seem to be ignored, basically it ignores all of these and just registers the user without checking if the code is valid.

Comment: How can you have "minus rows"? (`if ($rowCount < 0)`)

Comment: Print out your row count, maybe that's a problem

Comment: im checking if its less than 0, and if it is then the invite code doesnt exist

Comment: Maybe the single quotes around ***'$invite_code'*** ?

Comment: Removing quotes, didnt work.

Comment: If row count is _equal to_ zero then none were returned. It will not ever be less than zero.

Comment: Yea but i even tried doing if(!$result) so if the result dont return anything it should error but it doesnt it skips it and registers me...?

Comment: I tried with if(mysqli_num_rows($result1)<1) still didnt work and it ignores it...? :(

Comment: how about $rowCount == 0 ?

Comment: Nah still ignores it, man why tf is it ignoring everything i try.....

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: have you debuged your query by using echo and directly executing it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first your query execute successful. you can determine number of result after the query execute successful.

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Code, Name FROM Country ORDER BY Name")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

    /* close result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

checkout php manual for more information
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php